# Proof for certain matrix results?

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization

There are certain results of matrices that Stephen Boyd uses often in his book on Convex optimization. Can someone provide me proof for the results I have enumerated below:

1. If $B \in S^n$ and $A \in R^{p*n}$, then $x^TBx \geq 0$ for all $x \in N(A)$ if and only if there exist a $\lambda$ such that $B + \lambda AA^T \geq 0$
2. For any $p$ that satisfies $Ax = b$, any solution to the equation $Ax = b$ can be written as $x = p + v$ where $v \in N(A)$

Besides the proof an analogy to $R$ or $R^2$ would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: For item 1 of the question refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3423019/269050.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: Sufficiency is seen by looking at $x^T(B+\lambda A^TA)x$. Necessity can be proved as follows:

Assume that, for every $\lambda$, there exists a nonzero $y$ such that $y^T(B+\lambda A^T A)y < 0$. $y \in N(A)$ would then imply $y^T B y <0$ (solution modified from "Matrix Mathematics", Fact 8.15.24).

Q2: $A(p+v) = Ap + Av = b + 0 = b$, since $v$ is in the nullspace.

Comment: This proof is fine. But my problem is whether I will be able to cover all possible solutions to the equation $Ax = b$ using $p$ and  all $v \in N(A)$. Can you prove that?

Comment: Yes. If you define $v$ as $x-p$, you will see that $A(x-p) = 0$, so by definition $v \in N(A)$.

Comment: No you din't get my question. Let me try again. Suppose I have a matrix $Q$ whose range is equal to the null space of $A$. And I have a solution $p$ to the equation $Ax = b$. Also assume that the equation $Ax = b$ has $k$ solutions. My question is will I get all the $k$ solutions using $p + v$ where $v \in R(Q)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $k$ solutions? There will either be none, one, or an infinite number.

Comment: I am talking about both the cases where the system of equations has a solution and where the system of equations has infinite solutions.

Comment: You ask "whether I will be able to cover all possible solutions to the equation $Ax=b$ using $p$ and all $v\in N(A)$". I say yes, since if we set $v=x-p$ we see that it is in $N(A)$, so $x = p + (x-p)$. What am I missing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8076/discussion-between-ross-b-and-shirin)

Comment: sure.....That would be convenient.....Thanks for your time....

Comment: The argument is not correct because the assumption that $B+\lambda A^TA\not\geq0$ tells you that there is a $y$ such that $y^T(B+\lambda A^TA)y<0$, but this is not necessarily in $N(A)$.