# Positive semi-definiteness result

Tags: convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite

**Disclaimer:** This question had already been asked here [Proof for certain matrix results?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/341800/269050). However, the only answer provided there doesn't seem to be correct, so I'm re-stating it here (if this is not the expected procedure, please let me know.)

---

In the book **Convex Optimization** (Boyd-Vanderberghe), Chapter 3, Exercise 3.9 b) there is a hint whose proof I would love to learn:

*If $B\in S^n$ and $A\in{\Bbb R}^{p\times n}$, then $x^TBx\ge0$ for all $x\in{\rm ker}(A)$ if, and only if, there exists $\lambda$ such that $B+\lambda A^TA\succeq0$.*

---

The *if* part can be verified easily, so the problem is with the *only if* one. Unfortunately, the answer given to the old question doesn't prove the result at all (clearly). I've tried to relate this result with the fact that the minimum eigenvalue of $B$ equals $\min x^TBx$ for $\Vert x\Vert = 1$ without luck.

**More information.**
The solution to Exercise 3.44 a) published by the authors of the book includes a proof of this result for the particular case $p=1$, i.e., when $A$ is a row vector.

**Unfortunately**, the published proof (for $p=1$) has a mistake that renders the expression of the Schur complement incorrect.

Comment: You omit what about the mentioned answer "doesn't seem to be correct." The problem you pose seems to be asking for a proof of an if-and-only-if statement.  Does one direction of the implications seem easier than the other?  In short please add what work you've already done on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The result is not true

Here is a counter-example for the case $n=2$, $p=1$:
$$
     B = \begin{pmatrix}
         -1 &0 \\
          0 &1
          \end{pmatrix}, \qquad A = \begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The hypothesis is satisfied because ${\rm ker}\, A$ is generated by $(1,1)^T$ and
$$
    (1,1)\,B\,{1\choose1} = (1,1){-1\choose1} = 0 \ge 0.
$$
However, for any $\lambda$
$$
    B + \lambda AA^T = \begin{pmatrix}
                          -1 &0\\
                           0 &1
                       \end{pmatrix} +
                       \lambda\begin{pmatrix}
                                1 &-1\\
                                -1 & 1
                        \end{pmatrix} =
                        \begin{pmatrix}
                           -1+\lambda &-\lambda\\
                            -\lambda & 1 + \lambda
                        \end{pmatrix}
$$
whose characteristic polynomial $\chi(t) = t^2 -2\lambda t - 1$ has the negative root $\lambda - \sqrt{\lambda^2+1}$.

---

In the context of exercise 3.44 the counterexample corresponds to, e.g., $f(x,y)=-e^x + e^y$ at $(0,0)$.

---

In the context of exercise 3.9 a contraexample would be $f(x,y) = -e^x + e^y + x$, $A$ as above, $\hat{x} = (0,0)^T$ and
$$
   F = \begin{bmatrix}
         1 &0 \\
         1 &0
       \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
    Fz = (z_1, z_1)^T\qquad{\rm and}\qquad\tilde{f}(z) = z_1
$$
so $\nabla^2f(Fz+\hat{x})= B$ at $z=(0,0)^T$.

Comment: Nice find, I spent some time proving it but obviously without much success :) My two approaches where splitting up $x$ in two orthogonal parts (with one part in the kernel), and relating it to Appendix A.5.5.